# Bootstrap tabs - href link on one page to open or show tab on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried adding script to make a link go to another page and show the tab on that page when it loads but it doesn't seem to be working and I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction?
It will redirect to the correct page but does not change the tab to the correct tab.

Maybe I'm running the wrong jquery?

Here's the HTML:

```
      <div class="col-sm-4 hicon">
   <a href="services.html#houseremovals"><img src="img/hrhomeicon.jpg" alt="Home Removals icon"></a><br>Home Removals
  </div> 
  <div class="col-sm-4 hicon">
   <a href="services.html#students"><img src="img/slhomeicon.jpg" alt="Student Removals Icon"></a><br>Student Relocation
  </div>
```

And the js:

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 


$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

Maybe I'm not putting the javascript in the right location? I've got it loading at the bottom of each page to try it but nothing I do seems to get this working. I am using bootstrap 4 beta and jquery 3.2.1 if that helps?

Many thanks!

Comment: I understand that you want to click on a link and open a new tab with the marked tab showing. So why don't you try to use some GET parameter and show the tab index contained by that parameter? E.g.: `url.com/page?otherparams=othervalue&tab=1`. That would show tab 1. If I'm not explaying clearly just let me know.

Comment: I have tried a get parameter but I can't seem to get it to work, also tried using a simpler approach by just using a little bit of jquery: but still can't get it to work, very annoying, it just won't activate the tab I want it to at all. Must be something I'm missing! e.g. added : <a href="services.html?activeTab=students">  as the link on one page and then on the page with the tab I've added $activetabstudents = (params.activeTab == 'students') ? 'class="active"' : '';
 with <li $activetabstudents class="nav-item">
but does it work? Nope!